# How can SimpleXMLRPCServer registered function access the server itself and use some local scope?

Tags: python, oop

The SimpleXMLRPCServer allows you to register functions that can be then remotely called by clients. But truly, there is no use for this as I understand it now, because these functions cannot access some internal server scope.

Think just of a simple server that allows basic filesystem operations. To allow these, you need to remember current working directory at least, not talking about authentication. I prefer to define all server functions as static methods of the server class:

```
class FileRPCServer(SimpleXMLRPCServer):
    """
       This server extends SimpleXMLRPCServer and allows you to manipulate filesystem.
    """

    def __init__(self, currentWorkingDirectory, *args, **kwargs): 
        SimpleXMLRPCServer.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.cwd = currentWorkingDirectory
        self.register_introspection_functions() 
        #Default functions
        self.register_function(self.__class__.list_dir);

    @staticmethod
    def list_dir(dirname):
        ... prepend current working directory before dirname and do stuff ...

    @staticmethod
    def change_dir(dirname):
        ... change cwd to dirname, using current cwd if dirname is relative path ...
```

So as you can see I really need to actually access the object of the server that is running those xml-rpc functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to share state between ”functions” use a class and methods to encapsulate state and code in one object. So use real methods instead of static methods.

Also it's not a good idea to mix the RPC server with the program logic. I would create an own class for that.

A simple example implementing your two ”functions”:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# coding: utf8
from __future__ import absolute_import, division, print_function
import os
from SimpleXMLRPCServer import list_public_methods, SimpleXMLRPCServer


class Filesystem(object):

    def __init__(self, base_directory):
        self.current_directory = self.base_directory = os.path.normpath(
            os.path.abspath(base_directory)
        )

    def _listMethods(self):
        return list_public_methods(self)

    def _get_directory(self, dirname):
        if os.path.isabs(dirname):
            drive, _ = os.path.splitdrive(dirname)
            if drive:
                raise ValueError('trying to change drive')
            dirname = dirname.lstrip(os.sep + (os.altsep or ''))
            self.current_directory = self.base_directory

        result = os.path.normpath(
            os.path.abspath(os.path.join(self.current_directory, dirname))
        )
        print(result, self.base_directory)
        if not result.startswith(self.base_directory):
            raise ValueError('trying to go higher than base directory')
        return result

    def list_dir(self, dirname):
        return os.listdir(self._get_directory(dirname))

    def change_dir(self, dirname):
        self.current_directory = self._get_directory(dirname)
        return True


def main():
    server = SimpleXMLRPCServer(('localhost', 8000))
    server.register_introspection_functions()
    server.register_instance(Filesystem(u'.'))
    server.serve_forever()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I've tried to make the creation of the actual directory name in `_get_directory()` secure but please be careful with that as it is not tested as much as such a risky operation *should be* tested in a real server!

**Update**: Changed argument to `Filesystem` to unicode string to force result of `list_dir()` method to be unicode strings.

Comment: Thanks a lot - although I already figured it out this answer is really good addition to StackOverflow!